# Uninstalling a program after changing user folder name

Tags: windows, windows-10

On Windows 10, my user folder name used to be `C:\Users\name` but I changed it to `C:\Users\Name`. I've tried updating the desktop messaging app signal but it always says

```
Error opening file for writing
C:\Users\name\path\to\signal
```

For some reason Signal still seems to be trying to read and write to `C:\Users\name` instead of `C:\Users\Name`. I've tried uninstalling signal and reinstalling it but it throws the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Make a new Admin account, log into that and try uninstalling the program that way.

Comment: Another method I use, is from this new Admin account, is install this program, restart, and then uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Signal
2. Press Windows+R and type `%appdata%` and press enter
3. Rename the Signal folder to Signal_old
4. Reinstall Signal and pair it with your phone as usual

That should do the trick.